# .SMS file GSM 6 bit decoding

Tags: sms, gsm, decoding

I have to decode a file .SMS witch is encoded in GSM 6 bit(the SMS is not set from a cell phone but from some sensors to a base station, an then I get the .sms files). Can you help me with this any idea or tip? Thanks! 
There is a lot about 7 bit and 8 bit but nothing about 6 bit. Is is possible that is an user-defined alphabet?

Comment: How do you know that it is 6 bit coding?  Could it be a typo for 16 bit, i.e. UCS-2?

Comment: I open the file in notepad and it starts like this:"GSM-6bit@..."and continues with all the code. I also read the  manual from the sensors and base station that provide this information that they can provide .sms in 6 bit ecoding or 7 bit . So I this its pretty clear that myne is 6 bit since the beginning of the file its written "gsm6 bit". The characters (some of them) don't mach the characters from ascci-gsm7bit encoding tabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[3GPP TS 27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/27007.htm) Section 5.5 gives the allowed coding schemes supported by the AT+CSCS command.
As far as I am aware, none of them are 6 bit.  But it does say that

> (conversion schemes not listed here can be defined by manufacturers)

So it seems that as you suspected, you may have a user-defined alphabet.
How to deal with this?

If you can't get any information from the sender, then I would try fitting your messages to the first 6 bits of all of the officially supported conversion alphabets, to see if you can match all the characters.

Consider the contents of the messages - are they a limited character set, e.g. all numbers (0-9)?

It is possible that the sender may have used an official alphabet, maybe one that contains all the characters that they need in the first 6 bits, so they did not need to use the 7th and 8th bit.

Comment: Considering the contents of the message: we use an proprietary application provided by the manufacturer, in witch we load the .sms file and it give us an output .txt file with the data mostly numeric data. the TXT file has header witch is text(this is the same to all files) the actual information is just numbers and "." and a field with yes.- I think that is possible that all data in the .sms file would be just numbers and the header is added by the software and the yes/no filed would come from an original 0/1 field.